# Can Naruto use Wood Style?

Tags: naruto

After the Great Ninja War, Naruto's right arm was replaced by an artificial arm made up of Hashirama Senju's cells. To perform Wood Style, user requires a vast amount of chakra and Naruto can easily manage that.

Comment: Wood style has more than just chakra requirements. Its a Kekkei Genkai of chakra natures, which means that it requires an affinity for multiple elements, something which only a fraction of Shinobi have, and Naruto does not. Also, you may want to expand on the reasoning for including the artificial arm in the question here. As it stands, it looks like some random fact unrelated to the question, but considering how much I know about the Naruto series, it isn't or at least shouldn't seem so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wood Style requires water and earth affinity as it's a combination of these, while Naruto has wind affinity.

Using Combined Styles also requires Kekkei Genkai, which Naruto doesn't have.

So unless the author comes up with something in the future (like somehow forming his own chakra into the one he received from Hagoromo or into the chakras he received from the tailed beasts) Naruto is highly unlikely to be able to use Wood Style.

Comment: Who said Naruto has only wind chakra. That's only his natural nature affinity. In addition, he can use the other 4 nature affinities plus Lava, Magnet, Boil, Yin, Yang and Yin-Yang affinities. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki#Part%20I

Comment: Mastering a chakra type the user doesn't have affinity with requires a great amount of time and effort. Naruto is too young to have mastered two.

Comment: I couldn't edit so I'll continue:
Naruto is too young to have mastered two chakra types he doesn't have affinity with. (We know ha has some knowledge in earth, but that's it) || He can't use the chakra types you mentioned by himselh, rather he WAS able to use them when he had the tailed beasts' and Hagoromo's chakra. || Added some info to my answer about Kekkei Genkai

Comment: @SahanDeSilva Wood style is created not by using earth and water together, but by having an affinity for them, which allows you to use them together. Naruto does not have that affinity. The theory is that Naruto could do the same thing he does to create tailed beast chakra, but through the fake Hashirama arm. In theory, doing so, he could create wood style chakra, and control it. This has been shown to work in the past via Danzo, whos arm turned into a tree when he lost control of Hashiramas cells. So its all in theory that its possible, but I agree with Gorzius in that its unlikely he has.

Comment: Guys. All i said was that Naruto has more than Wind nature affinity. I never argued that he could / couldn't master wood style. :)

Answer (score -1):

Given that Naruto has access to Six Paths Sage Mode - a power that gives him instantaneous mastery over the five basic Changes in Chaka Nature + that of Yin-Yang Release, is a reincarnation of Indra Otsutsuki - a power that grants him access to his ultimate form, Asura Kurama Mode, as well gained the affinity of the remaining tailed beasts and was thusly able to master Lava, Boil, and Magnet Release, as seen in Sage Art: Super Tailed Beast Rasenshuriken, I see no reason why Naruto - now also in procession of an arm grafted from cells of the First Hokage, Hashirama Senju, who, despite not being a member of the Otsutsuki clan, mastered Wood Release - should (in theory), be able to use Wood Style were he to meditate on the earth- and water-based nature combination Kekki Genkai using the Six Paths' power.

Comment: Implanting Hashirama's cells do not immediately mean you can use Wood Release. Remember Orochimaru's experiment? Only Yamato was the successful one out of many candidates. There's a possibility he can but there's also a possibility he cannot.

Comment: naruto is a reincarnation of asura otsutsuki not indra

Answer (score -1):

I would like to believe that he can. There are a few evidences that show this.
 SPOILER ALERT

After gaining Sage of Six Paths powers he was show to be able to use several kekkai genkai including magnet release, and lava release. While fighting white zetsu his Kyubi cloak the defeated zetsus where turned into a cloak with the 9 tails chakra. During the fight with Pain, after Naruto became enraged and released the 4 tailed cloak, we can see naruto raise a large forest of roots from the ground similar to the Deep Forest Emergence used by Hashirama

Comment: Sources? Chapters? Episode numbers? Possibly screenshots? Because I could not remember Naruto ever using wood style. Just because he unlocked the other kekkai genkai doesn't mean he can automatically use Wood release.